# How to get a whole HTML page in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to get the content of a whole HTML page **generated from AngularJS code** (*e.g: the page contains Angular code*) as a string variable.

For example, with the following code:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myVar = 'Hello world!';
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{myVar}}
</div>
```

I would like to get:

```
var myHtml = '<div>Hello world!</div>';
```

How can I do that?

---

### [JSFiddle of the code](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/dxah4p7c/2/)

Comment: Try using $sce https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: cant you do something like: "var myHtml = document.querySelector('div[ng-app]').innerHTML"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxah4p7c/4/) and make it work. In your case, this synthax should work:

```
document.querySelector('div[ng-app]').innerHTML;
```

---

#### View

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>{{myVar}}</div>
    <button ng-click="getTheDamnHoleHTML()">
        Collect the whole AngularJS Application HTML/DOM
    </button>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myVar = 'Hello world!';

  $scope.getTheDamnHoleHTML = function () {
    console.log(document.querySelector('div[ng-app]').innerHTML);
  }
}]);
```